# Sending variable data to server using XMLHttpRequest Get method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to send one variable data to server using Get method in `XMLHttpRequest`. When we use `Get` type then we cannot send it in the body like Post so how can I send that variable `xyz` to server ..

```js
function getSearch() {

  var xyz = "vincent";
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/google.com/exec';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var link = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();

}
```

Comment: Append query parameters to your URL, eg `...exec?xyz=' + encodeURIComponent(xyz)`

Answer (score 1):

One such approach is to encode the parameters into your URL, hence you'll need to modify your code as per below.

Add the following line, where some_variable_name is the parameter name you're planning to pass across.

```
var params = "some_variable_name=xyz";
url = url + '?' + params;
```

Modify your xhr.open to include the new parameter:

```
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
```

Your code would look something like this:

```js
function getSearch() {

  var xyz = "vincent";
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/google.com/exec';
  var params = '?some_variable_name=' + encodeURIComponent(xyz);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  url = url + params;
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var link = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    }
  }

  xhr.send();

}
```

Comment: `http` is not defined anywhere in your answer. You probably meant `xhr`

Comment: thanks Phil for the pick up - have amended my code to reflect the feedback

Answer (score 0):

First make sure what type of data you want to send , if data is sensitive like password,email etc do not send it with the get request use post instead, although if you want to send param/varible data from get send it with URL query parameter like below

```
var xyz = "vincent";
var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/google.com/exec'+'? {name_of_param}='+xyz;
```

and at server you will be able to get the variable data by , **req.query.{name_of_param}**

Good luck

Comment: ...thanks phil and AB ...i am using Appscript at server end ....function doGet(e)
{ }; i need to receive that variable data in this method

Comment: The doGet function has a single parameter - e. To access to an url parameter services e.parameter.Param_Name. Here are more details  http://google-data-api.blogspot.com/2011/06/get-url-parameter-from-published-google.html

Comment: var xyz="vincent";
       var url = 'https:macros/exec'+'?name='+xyz;

Comment: in my appscript i gave like this  function doGet(e) {  var nameF = e.parameter.name; }   when i print nameF its giving me nameF is Undefined

Comment: what is your url which you use with XMLHttpRequest

Comment: u will not have access to that url

Comment: could you show me at what URL you are requesting from frontend (XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gnNj6NFErrRY0NqEBVuYzPcxJ8hnFPzZ01QDeo8xAW4/exec        .. like this it will be ...when i deploy my code i will get one exec link ..